# Como verificar se a janela do tkinter foi fechada Python?

Tags: python

**Eu estou tendo um problema com o código, o meu código é maior do q isso, essa parte é só a parte de login e senha, o meu problema é q o código funciona se caso a janela for fechada pelo X, tem como verificar se a janela do tkinter foi fechada pelo X e fechar o programa inteiro se isso foi feito?**

```
#Criar janela de login
jan = Tk()
jan.title('Login System')
jan.geometry("250x150")
jan.resizable(width=False, height=False)

#Definir funções
def Logar():
    User = en1.get()
    Pass2 = en2.get()

    DataBase.cur.execute("""
    SELECT * FROM LoginUsers
    WHERE (User = ? and Password = ?)
    """, (User, Pass2))
    VerifyLogin = DataBase.cur.fetchone()
    try:
        if User in VerifyLogin and Pass2 in VerifyLogin:
            messagebox.showinfo(title='Login Info', message='Acesso Confirmado. Bem Vindo')
            jan.destroy()

    except:
        messagebox.showerror(title='Login Info', message='Acesso Negado. Verifique se você esta cadastrado no sistema.')

def RegisterData():
    Name = en1.get()
    Pass = en2.get()

    if Name == "" and Pass == "":
        messagebox.showerror(title="Register Error", message="Preencha todos os camos")
    else:
        DataBase.cur.execute("""
        INSERT INTO LoginUsers(User, Password) VALUES(?, ?)
        """, (Name, Pass))
        DataBase.conn.commit()
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Register Info", message="Registrado Com Sucesso")

#Criar Widgets
text1 = Label(jan, text='Login: ')
text2 = Label(jan, text='Passworld: ')
en1 = Entry(jan)
en2 = Entry(jan, show='*')
bt1 = Button(jan, text='Confirm', command=Logar)
bt2 = Button(jan, text='Register', command=RegisterData)

#Posicionar Widgets
text1.grid(row=0, column=0)
text2.grid(row=1, column=0)
en1.grid(row=0, column=1)
en2.grid(row=1, column=1)
bt1.grid(row=2, column=1)
bt2.grid(row=3, column=1)

#Deixar a janela em loop
jan.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

E assim eu não sei quais são as outras partes do código mas teoricamente se for fechado pelo X o sistema operativo para todos os processos relacionados por isso pode se dizer que sim

PS: Eu entendi que te estavas a referir ao X vermelho do canto superior esquerdo e foi nisso que me basiei

Comment: Sim, o X é aquele vermelho

Comment: https://github.com/VitorPL07/assistente
Esse são os arquivos.

Comment: Eu acredito que sim mas o q e q estava a correr errado com o codigo?

Comment: Se o usuário fechar a tela de login pelo X o programa continua, e não é pra isso acontecer.
Eu quero q se caso o usuário fechar a janela pelo X, o programa saia

Comment: como e sabes que o programa não sai por completo o que e q te da essa indicação

Comment: Pq eu testei, o programa é eu q tô fazendo

Answer (score -1):

Depois de instanciar a janela de execução, basta fazer uma verificação, sendo assim, se a janela do tkinter for fechada o seu programa será terminado.

```
if jan.quit() == True:
    jan.destroy()
else:
   text1 = Label(jan, text='Login: ')
   text2 = Label(jan, text='Passworld: ')
en1 = Entry(jan)
en2 = Entry(jan, show='*')
bt1 = Button(jan, text='Confirm', command=Logar)
bt2 = Button(jan, text='Register', command=RegisterData)

#Posicionar Widgets
text1.grid(row=0, column=0)
text2.grid(row=1, column=0)
en1.grid(row=0, column=1)
en2.grid(row=1, column=1)
bt1.grid(row=2, column=1)
bt2.grid(row=3, column=1)

#Deixar a janela em loop
jan.mainloop()
```